# Open source, command-line tool to convert Excel .xls to .xlsx without Excel

Tags: windows, command-line, microsoft-excel, file-format, xls

I'm looking for an open source, command-line tool to convert files from the old, binary Excel ".xls" format to the new (Excel 2007) Open XML .xlsx, without Excel installed, on a Windows PC.

Ideas?

Edit: Open source is strongly preferred, but free for commercial usage is ok too.

Edit: Additional software, such as Excel Viewer, can be installed on the system, as long as open/free for commercial usage.

Comment: Does it actually need to be open source? Or just free?

Comment: Hi, as I know it should be possible to run LibreOffice in CMD mode - even on a server. However I do not have further experience with it.

Comment: [This reference](http://help.libreoffice.org/Common/About_Converting_Microsoft_Office_Documents) says that LibreOffice *cannot* be used to save in Open XML format; it can only read. Might have to look for other options?

Comment: Would it be possible to have [Excel Viewer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/273711) installed?

Comment: Editing your post is fair for the others to know about it but you can mention the user who asked you about the Open Source/Free. By the way you still don't mention is any freeware preferable from you or not?